# Why do I get errors using shift-enter to run Python code in my IDE?

Tags: python, visual-studio, indentation

I am a newbie trying to use Python (2.17.15 via Anaconda) on **Visual Stodio Code** on my Mac. I have the following simple code:

```
def function(x):
    y = x + 2
    return y
```

This code is giving me the usual trouble, an **indentation error**:

```
   return y
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>     return y
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    return y
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>
```

Needless to say that Jupyter or Spyder have no problem with this. I checked that on VSC tab gives 4 spaces. All similar questions are related to this, but I cannot fix it.

Other, built in functions of Python work fine.

Please give me some help or tips since I do not know how to escape this.

**UPDATE**

Installing again Python3 this simple code DOES work on Sublime but still not on VS Code. I still get the same error in VS Code.

**UPDATE2**

So, another update. If I change from `return` to `print` and instead of shift-command debug and run the code then it works.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Just by the way here, but I'd recommend learning Python 3 instead of Python 2. Python 2 is scheduled for End Of Life next year.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I know, I am working with both since some finance stuff uses Python 2. But thank you.

Comment: @Marion Not sure what difference the `print` makes, but using "Debug/Run" will work because it's running the entire script, and your script is fine (i.e. it's valid Python). The issue is the bug I mentioned in my answer, and while there are workarounds for the issue (the ones mentioned in my issue) there's still a bug in VS Code causing it to fail to run snippets that include indentation.

Comment: @Marion I *think* my answer (below) is a good answer to your question, but I agree...it's not the answer you're looking for. My suggestion is that you add your comments to the GitHub issue I've linked so that the VS Code team see this as an important issue. And, if you were to upvote, or mark my answer as correct, that would also be awesome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like it's because you're running the code with Shift+ENTER.

VS Code has the following **2** bindings for Shift_ENTER:

[image]

I believe that you're seeing the 2nd of these, which says "Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal. I suspect you have the focus on the `return y` line, and so it's only running that single line of code.

If, instead of Shift+ENTER, you use the Run Code command in VS Code, you should see it work fine:

[image]

You might well think "OK...so if I select all of the code this will work, right?" and I agree...this feels like it should work. However, I see a similar issue. I'll see if I can work out why, but for the moment you can use the Run Code command in VS Code and that will do what you want. If you highlight the code you want to run, that will limit what gets executed.

Run Code can be executed with `Ctrl+Alt+N`

It looks like this issue (that selected code doesn't run correctly with Shift+ENTER) is a bug that's being tracked by here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2837

And a work around (not ideal) is to add code before/after your function that is NOT indented, and then select and execute those lines too:

```py
print("this...")

def function(x):
    y = x + 2
    return y

print("...now works if you select all these lines and Shift+ENTER!")
```

Comment: Ok, I did it but it does not help. Thanks though.

Comment: Are you able to show what you see? Are you also able to give a little more of the file that's causing a problem?

Comment: this is all of the file. I have no other code. Just trying to set up VSC because I like it for HTML and CSS. I get the same message as quoted in my question...

Comment: I've just enhanced my answer...notice that this is reported on Line 1, not Line 3. I suspect your line endings might be to blame.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do something else. I tried to import to VSC a Jupyter file and run it via "Python Interactive". There I get no issues.  Another point is that using tab won't give me an arrow rather it will give me 4 dots. I do get an error in Line 3 when I don't use tab for the print command (i.e. when it lies below def)

Comment: Actually...can you tell me how you're executing your code? Are you just executing a single line (the return line)?

Comment: I am pressing shift+enter. Since there is one piece of code it executes all of it.

Comment: OK. I see same thing. I will amend my answer shortly.

Comment: Yeah, no matter what I do, I cannot run simple python code with VS code..

Comment: @SeanMcCarthy ... you feel that the IDE is not mature because it offers an "execute single line" feature that OP accidentally inappropriately used on code that isn't a valid single line (but is only valid as part of a larger whole)?

Comment: That was many years ago. I love VS Code now and use it all day every day. It's come so far.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug from the [python extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13015), which you need to run chunks of code in the interactive mode.

So in the example code below:

```
for lastRun in list(d_RunPanelsPresent.keys()): 

    # some indented commands
    logFile = f"/nexusb/Novaseq/{lastRun}/logPPscript.txt"
    if not os.path.isfile(logFile):
        with open(logFile, 'w+') as f:
            pass
    else:
        pass
```

If I highlight as follows (note where the cursor is):

[image]

I will get an error.

The solution is to **highlight the code from the very left of the code editor**, as shown below:

[image]

This works for me 100% of the time.

Answer (score -1):

Forgetting a semicolon at the end of the function definition produces the same error.